# What to enter in Redirect plugin? (4.6.2)

Tags: redirect, impresspages

What syntax do I have to enter for getting correct redirects? 
No matter if I enter for example 
 /english/project-management or http://www.URL.com/english/project-management it won't work. Neither with source not with target URL. 
Trailing / or not doesn't make any difference either.

Or have I completely misunderstood this feature?

Answer (score 0):

You have to enter a full URL http://..... or use * symbol to mark any number of any characters.

Be careful, it is possible to do an infinite loop or break admin.

Comment: That does not work here - I get a 404 when I enter the full old URL which I want to translate to the new one. 
The new one exists but there seems to be no reaction to capture and redirect the old one.

Comment: Does the old URL resolves to the new ImpressPages installation? This plugin meant to do redirects inside the website. If you had an old domain that doesn't work, this plugin can't magically make it work.
The easiest way to add redirects to this plugins is as follow:
from: */something
to: http://example.com/somethingelse